# How to get All the get request and responses

Tags: wireshark, wireshark-dissector

Hi I have browsed some data and captured the traces in Wiresshark.
Is there anyway or filter that we can get all the get requests and there responses only in Wireshark.

Answer (score 1):

[Wireshark display filter](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/wsug_html_chunked/ChWorkDefineFilterSection.html):

```
http.request || http.response
```

Answer (score 0):

You can filter Wireshark's output using many criterias, like the protocols used, source and destination address/ports, and so on. It really depends on what kind of requests/responses you want to filter. For further information, take a look at

https://wiki.wireshark.org/DisplayFilters.